# Jquery Validation using class

Tags: jquery

hi i am try to do some validation for dynamic text box.based on class.
if both text value are same my form should not submit.i am already written one condition .but it always show same value;
this is my code

```
$('.option_text').each(function(){

        if($(this).val() ==''){
            alert('Option Cannot Empty');
            $('.add_option_table').show();
            $('.add_questions').hide();
            $(this).focus(); 
            submitAllow=false;
            return false;

        }else if($(this).val()==$(this).val()){
            alert('Option Value Shoud not Same');
            $('.add_option_table').show();
            $('.add_questions').hide();
            $(this).focus(); 
            submitAllow=false;
            return false;
        }

});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()==$(this).val()` is always going to be true

Comment: check this plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: use JQuery's `.live()`

Comment: You mind giving the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I think `$(this).val()==$(this).val()` will give you always the same value, hence it will always be true. Store previous value in another container.

Answer (score 0):

Here it will always show the same value as your comparing the same element with it self.
$(this) would refer to the current element.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
if($(this).val()==$(this).val())
```

Will always be true. Instead try checking their siblings' values. Change your code this way:

```
if($(this).val()==$(this).siblings().val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden element(let's say id="HiddenVal") where you can store all textbox values entered till now.This can be
done by calling the following function

```
function getPrevValues(){
var AllValues=[];
$('.option_text').each(function(){
AllValues.push($(this).val());
});
$('#HiddenVal').val(AllValues);
}
```

Now whenever you enter new value, call a function like checkAvailability(this)

```
function checkAvailability(id){
var AllValues=$('#HiddenVal').val().split(',');
if($.inArray($(id).val(),AllValues)>-1)
alert('You can add')
else
alert('you cant add');
}
```

Comment: If i use above condition it take only first and last..but my fields are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child` to target different elements of the same class.

```
$('.option_text:nth-child(1)') == $('.option_text:nth-child(2)');
```

Like the others stated `$(this).val()==$(this).val()` will always be true.